# Flex 3 Trying to add a diagonal image to fields on a grid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, tooltip, background-image, bitmapdata

here is the existing chunk of code:

```
if (status != FlexFieldInfo.EDITABLE) {
            setToolTip(uiComponent, status, entityForm);
            graphics.beginFill(0xFFABC0);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            graphics.endFill();
```

i would like to replace the background color with a tiling background-image.

i understand that "graphics." can only fill or draw. i understand the chunk of "graphics." in the code above needs to change to something else, but i am at a loss of how to call the following image: `background-image: Embed("images/bg-uneditableField.jpg");`

I have searched high and low unsuccessfully. I am a front-end developer just stepping in to our Flex 3 environment and am not a strong javascript/.as person.

Note: our application needs to stay in Flex 3, upgrading is not an option at this time.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To get your background image you can use the following code:

```
var backgroundClass:Class = getStyle("backgroundImage");
```

Then you can instantiate this class and fill with it (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/BitmapAsset.html)):

```
var bitmapAsset:BitmapAsset = new backgroundClass();
var bitmapData:BitmapData = bitmapAsset.bitmapData;
```

The perform filling (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginBitmapFill%28%29)):

```
graphics. beginBitmapFill(bitmapData);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: thank you for this... i'm trying to make it work. i'll let you know when i finally figure it out. i'm just learning how flex3 works and imports and everything else. i'm struggling, but i'm trying to get a successful build.